# Getting co-ordinates of bitmap on mouseDown in NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pixel, nsimageview, nspoint

I am working on an app where I display unsupported (by XCode) file format). So I've subclassed `NSBitmapImageRep` to display it in a subclass of `NSImaageView`. I've set it up to be proportionally scallable (up or down). Now I need to add a possibility to get coordinates of pixel in a bitmap. So I've ovveride mouseDown: method:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"mouseDown: %ld", [theEvent clickCount]);
    NSPoint point = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSLog(@"point x: %f and y: %f", point.x, point.y);    
}
```

After getting NSPoint I should try to convert it to co-ordinates of a bitmap BUT first I have no idea How to solve the problem that locationInWindow returns `NSPoint` of a `NSImageView`, not of the bitmap which is ussually smaller and has unused margins in `NSImageView`, but I can click on the margin and mouseDown event returns me `NSPoint` in that margin. Do you have any idea what I shoud do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a view to image matrix. It's a matrix that maps view coordinates to image coordinates. Usually it will be a combination of scale and translation.

First you need to decide if you want to scale the image so that it is entirely visible, but fits within the window, or so that it entirely fills the window. (Or there are other options, like always showing the image at 1:1 regardless of the size of the window.) That will determine the scale of the image.

Next you need to decide how to position the scaled image. If you scale it to always fit in the window, and there's padding, do you favor the left and top of the window, or always try to center it? IF it's scaled to always fill the window, is it centered vertically or horizontally in the window? Or is the origin of the image always displayed in the lower left of the window?

Once you've figured out the scale and translate, you can compose a single matrix from the 2 of them. Once you've done that, get the inverse of the matrix, and that will transform your view coordinates into image pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I thought that this task will be less complex. Please explain me in more detail what do you mean "get the inverse of the matrix". Maybe is there a 3rd party libraries to manage  images pixel by pixel (and getting their coordinates on mouseDown of course)? Do you know any?

Comment: If you have a transform matrix, it transforms coordinates from one space to another. The inverse of the matrix transforms them back. But in this case, you don't need to use a full matrix. You only need scale and translate. If you have the scale and translation to go in one direction, just invert the scale and subtract the translation to go in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on it now and think that it will work. By the way  locationInWindow method returns NSPoint object in the base coordinate system of the associated window not of the NSImageView (this is in documentation but I didn't realize that in the first moment). Once again - thanks!